# how to change this code from objective-c to swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

how to change this code from objective-c to swift :

```
- (void)get_answer_dict:(NSDictionary *)dict_1:(NSDictionary *)dict_2{

}
```

i write to:

```
func get_answer_dict(dict_1: [NSObject: AnyObject], dict_2: [NSObject: AnyObject])
    {

    }
```

but not ok .....

//err out put

```
2016-05-28 10:09:23.815 Meet Design[32299:919087] -[Meet_Design.DesignerScroll get_answer_dict::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa8af32670
2016-05-28 10:09:23.825 Meet Design[32299:919087] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Meet_Design.DesignerScroll get_answer_dict::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa8af32670'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c67fd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bd44deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c688d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c5cecfa ___forwarding___ + 970
```

Comment: Just set NSDictionary as the data type.

Comment: You haven't shared whether you're changing the implementation of the method from Objective-C to Swift, or the calling of the method, or both. Perhaps you can update the question with example of how you're calling this method. Frankly, I'm a little surprised by your error message, as I would have expected you to get compile-time warnings. Did you not get any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Objective-C method declaration is using a method signature style without named parameters, which we generally don't use anymore. Are you wed to that style, or would you use the more contemporary style? But if you really wanted to implement a Swift method without named parameters, it would be something like:

```
func get_answer_dict(dict_1: [NSObject: AnyObject]!, _ dict_2: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
   ...
}
```

You could then call that from Swift as:

```
obj.get_answer_dict(dictionary1, dictionary2)
```

Or from Objective-C:

```
[obj get_answer_dict:dictionary1 :dictionary2];
```

---

Having said that, I'd heartily encourage you to use more conventional method naming conventions, eg.

```
- (void)retrieveAnswerWithDictionary1:(NSDictionary *)dictionary1 dictionary2:(NSDictionary *)dictionary2 {
    ....
}
```

And you'd call that as

```
[obj retrieveAnswerWithDictionary1:someDictionary dictionary2:someOtherDictionary];
```

The Swift equivalent would be:

```
func retrieveAnswerWithDictionary1(dictionary1: [NSObject: AnyObject], dictionary2: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
    ...
}
```

Which would be called:

```
obj.retrieveAnswerWithDictionary1(someDictionary, dictionary2: someOtherDictionary)
```

Note, not only are the parameters named, but I use camelCase naming convention and no underscores.

Frankly, I would be more specific in the typing of the key and value types to the dictionaries, too, but I'll leave that to you. One of the key benefits of Swift is that takes type-safety more seriously than Objective-C, so we generally wouldn't use `NSObject` or `AnyObject` unless we absolutely had to.

Comment: your code is ok,   thank you very much.

 what is the better of your "conventional method naming conventions "  ???

Comment: The value of naming conventions is that it's something that any programmer can pick up and follow. And if you have additional developers programming, you know everyone is on the same page. For particulars on what the naming conventions are, see [Naming Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html) in _Coding Guidelines for Cocoa._ But more important than the naming of the method is that the subsequent parameters always have a name. Many programmers haven't even seen the nameless parameter convention you've used.

Comment: And I'd suggest that giving all the parameters a name (the first parameter's name is incorporated into the method name) lends much more readable code. It eliminates guessing what the subsequent parameters are.

Comment: thanks,  maybe i  try your advice in sometime.   but i more like  KISS principle( "Keep it simple, stupid")